# Python nested for-loops returning wrong result (?)

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have a question concerning this piece of code:

```
def new_field():
    global field
    field= [[]]*9
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(1,10):
            field[x].append([y," "])
    return field
```

The way I understand for-loops, it should return a list like this:
[[[1, " "], [2, " "], [3, " "], ...[9, " "]], [1, " "], [2, " "], ...

which would mean that field should have a length of 9 for every index from 0 to 8 ->

`len(field[0])` should be 9. Instead the length is 81 for every index, what should be the entire list can be found in every sublist.

It looks like this:

```
[[[1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [1, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [2, ' '], [3, ' '], [3, ' '], [3, ' '], [3, ' '], [3, ' '], [3, ' '], .......
```

Now I have a feeling that I simply dont understand how exactly for-loops work, but I just dont get what I am missing or where the problem in my thoughtprocess is.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 4):

> The way I understand for-loops ...

Yes, but you misunderstand references.

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b
[1]
```

You need to create the sublist new each time.

```
field = [[] for x in range(9)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I focused too much on the wrong part of my code. This actually helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with this line:

```
field= [[]]*9
```

Instead, it needs to be like this:

```
field= [[] for _ in range(9)]
```

This is because the current code is creating a list that has 9 copies of the *same* list.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> x = [[]]*2
>>> x
[[], []]
>>> id(x[0]) == id(x[1]) # The lists have the same id, so they are the same
True
>>> x = [[] for _ in range(2)]
>>> x
[[], []]
>>> id(x[0]) == id(x[1]) # The lists have different ids, so they are different
False
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I will try that out right now, thanks!

Comment: @user2299050:  Don't just try it out.  Make sure you understand *why* this works and yours doesn't.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm actually asking this question to learn, I already had a solution to my problem by "bypassing" the issue.